# Built-in Tcl types internal representation

Tags: c, tcl

I building a program that uses Tcl as its command interface. As part of the integration I have defined a few custom `Tcl_ObjType`'s and a few commands implemented in C/C++ with `Tcl_CreateObjCommand`.

When parsing the command arguments I am not sure if my handling of the built in types is complete.

Is there a description somewhere of what the fields of an object(`Tcl_Obj`) of any of the 6(?) built-in types looks like?

Thinking of a table like this, showing the Tcl_Obj field values:

```
Human     |       |           |
type name | bytes | type      | internalRep
----------------------------------------------------------------
scalar    | value | NULL      | all NULL
list      | NULL  | "list"    | otherValuePtr has the value
array     | NULL  | "dict"    | ???
file      | ???   | "channel" | ???
?????     | ???   | ?????     | ???
?????     | ???   | ?????     | ???
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no exact documentation precisely because it is a user-extensible type. However, I can point out a few things.

All values have either a non-NULL `bytes` field or a non-NULL `typePtr` field, or both. For a small integer, the `typePtr` (which is a sort of vtable, if you know C++) will indicate that it is an `int`, and the `longValue` member of the `internalRep` holds what the value is. When that small integer is used as a string, its `bytes` and `length` fields get populated (by calling the `updateStringProc` of the `typePtr`). For large integers, the value is stored as a pointer to an `mp_int` (in the `otherValuePtr`). For floating point values, it's the `doubleValue` field.

Lists and dicts actually both use the `twoPtrValue`; the secondary pointer is used when invalidating a tree of values during an update (and is otherwise NULL). Behind the primary pointer is a pointer to a `List` or `Dict` struct, respectively, and those are internally ref-counted and managed.

However, the exact meaning of the fields depends on the `typePtr` and is only typically known by a small API that knows how to talk about them, and everything else *including inside Tcl itself* does not peek behind the curtain. It is good style to think about conceptually giving your functions a tighter type signature and then using the likes of `Tcl_GetIntFromObj` or `Tcl_ListObjGetElements` to enforce the signature; the functions enforce and cache the types. If you're making your own, the simplest method *by far* is to start from the string form (which you can always get with `Tcl_GetStringFromObj`, which never errors) and then work from there. The most common third-party types are all caches that allow skipping a look up via a hash table or other map. Other possibilities exist of course.

---

We don't have a complete list of internal types. The easiest thing might be to experiment with `tcl::unsupported::representation` in Tcl 8.6, as that allows you to take a peek at what is going on in a limited fashion without resorting to writing C code. Just remember that peeking at the type is very bad style; it's intended as a debugging tool only.

Comment: We can look up specific types, but that's really just “read the source code”. Tcl's language-level types are considered to be an implementation detail, not part of the API.